# Why are there spaces in my paragraph when using <a href> tag?

Tags: html, css, anchor

i have been troubling about the way how i put this single text in paragraph tag. but everytime i add the anchor tag it keeps entering i want it to be at the side of the text not below. please help me.

[this is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKL0D.jpg)

and this is the code

ccs:

```css
<style>
div.box {
 width: 168px;
 height: 300px;
 margin: 10px;
 float:left;
 background-color:#333;
}
table.shop {
 height: 450px;
 overflow-y:scroll;
 display: block;
}
ul.aa {
 list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
li {
 float:left;
}
a {
 display:block;
 width: 200px;
}
a.head:link {text-decoration:none; font-family:"Century Gothic"; font-size:18px; color:#FFF;}
a.head:visited {text-decoration:none; font-family:"Century Gothic"; font-size:18px; color:#FFF;}
a.head:hover {text-decoration:none; font-family:"Century Gothic"; font-size:18px; color:#FFF;}
a.head:active {text-decoration:underline; font-family:"Century Gothic"; font-size:18px; color:#FFF;}

a.foot:link {text-decoration:none; font-family:"Century Gothic"; font-size:18px; color:#FFF;}
a.foot:visited {text-decoration:none; font-family:"Century Gothic"; font-size:18px; color:#FFF;}
a.foot:hover {text-decoration:none; font-family:"Century Gothic"; font-size:18px; color:#FFF;}
a.foot:active {text-decoration:underline; font-family:"Century Gothic"; font-size:18px; color:#FFF;}
</style>
```

And the html:

```html
  <!--================================================-->
    <!--========this will be the start of the body====-->
    <!--================================================-->
  <tr>
    <td height="450" background="background.jpg" valign="top">
    <br />
    <br />
    <center><img src="Thanks.png" alt="thankyou" /></center>
    <table align="center" width="700">
     <tr>
         <td>
    <font face="Century Gothic" color="#FFFFFF" size="+1"><p align="center">You will receive a response shortly regarding to your order. The e-mail will contain the price and other details concering about your order. If some details appears to be wrong please reply immediately to the e-mail. once again, thank you so much! <a class="one" href="index.php">Click Here</a> to return to home page.</p></font>
      </td>
         </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
    <!--================================================-->
    <!--========this will be the end of the body========-->
    <!--================================================-->
```

could you please help me solve this problem?

Comment: `center`, `font` and `table` based layouts? Did you learn HTML from a book from 1996?

Comment: im only starting to use html, so what?

Comment: You're learning the wrong stuff then.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to put your link inline with the rest of the message.

Right now, the link is being pushed down because of the css:

```
a {
   display:block;
   width: 200px;
}
```

Instead, you want it inline with the rest of your text, so you can do

```
a {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

That should fix your problem!

Comment: No need to make it an inline-block - just remove the CSS that you had for a overall and it works.

Comment: That's true ^ forgot links are default inline.